# Call own method from module async

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I have my `app.js`, which has the following endpoint. This endpoint obviously acts weird, because it expects data to return before it says `res.send(data)`, which is the wrong way to do Node.js.

I am not sure how to modify my code, so I get the data from `users.GetUsers`, and can send it to the client `with res.send(data)`.

**App.js code**:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var users = require('./users');

client = redis.createClient();
var app = express();
var port = 4000;

app.listen(port);

app.get('/users',function(req,res) {
    var data = users.getUsers(req,res);
    console.log('data: ' + data);
    res.send(data);
});
```

**My users module**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var redis = require('redis');
client = redis.createClient();

exports.getUsers = function(req,res) {
    var cacheKey = 'userKey';

    //client.del(cacheKey);

    client.get(cacheKey,function(err,data) {
        if(err || data === null) {
            mongoose.model('users').find(function(err,users) {
                console.log('Setting cache: ' + cacheKey);
                client.set(cacheKey,users,redis.print);
                return users;
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Find data in cache');
            return data;
        }
    });
};
```

**My problem**:

My variable `data` in `App.js`, will always be undefined. How do I modify my call, so I can get the data to the server when it is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a value from a callback is meaningless because the return value is almost always ignored. Instead what is typically done is a callback is passed to the asynchronous function. Then inside your function, you execute the callback with an error as the first argument (`null`/`undefined` if no error) and then your results as the second or more arguments.

Example:

app.js:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  users.getUsers(req, res, function(err, data) {
    console.log('data: ' + data);
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

users.js:

```
exports.getUsers = function(req, res, cb) {
  var cacheKey = 'userKey';

  //client.del(cacheKey);

  client.get(cacheKey,function(err, data) {
    if (err || data === null) {
      mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users) {
        console.log('Setting cache: ' + cacheKey);
        client.set(cacheKey, users, redis.print);
        cb(err, users);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Find data in cache');
      cb(null, data);
    }
  });
};
```